# Foreign Data Wrapper elasticsearch postgresql

Tags: postgresql, elasticsearch, foreign-data-wrapper, multicorn

I tried to perform postgresql and Elasticsearch together using Foreign Data Wrapper. I have followed this : https://github.com/Mikulas/pg-es-fdw

When I insert new articles, everything is working but when I try to update or delete, it show me some errors :

```
ERROR: Cannot transform anything else than mappings andsequences to rows
État SQL :XX000
Contexte : SQL statement "DELETE FROM articles_es a WHERE a.id = OLD.id"
PL/pgSQL function delete_article() line 3 at SQL statement
```

Anyone could help me?
Thanks!